# Matrix multiplication with variable number of matrices

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have a *group of matrices* as below

```
import numpy as np
Number = 10
mylist = [np.random.randint(1, 5, size=(4, 4)) for i in range(Number)]
```

Now I want to matrix-multiply all matrices in `mylist` **at once**. Here value of `Number` may change

Is there any method/function available to perform this?

Comment: `np.linalg.multi_dot(mylist)`? 20x slower than `functools.reduce`, interesting.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny A great comment. Regarding `multi_dot` performance check out
https://stackoverflow.com/q/45852228/1328439. In essence, `multi_dot` is best for large matrices where optimized multiplication order pays off.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov - Thanks. I benchmarked only with `((n,n), float64)` matrices up to `(100,100,100)`. I didn't even notice the application to other suitable matrices.

Comment: `multi_dot` is still doing repeated `dot`.  Your arrays are all the same shape, so order doesn't matter.  And the values are different, so you can't take advantage of grouping them (as a matrix power would).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is native in the `np.linalg` package:

```
np.linalg.multi_dot(mylist)
```

Comment: I swear I didn't see @MichaelSzczesny 's comment first >.<

Comment: It is native, but still using python code.  It doesn't add a compiled layer.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that easily with the reduce function of the functools package:

```py
import functools

result = functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a @ b, mylist)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `functools.reduce`

```
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce
Number = 10
mylist = [np.random.randint(1, 5, size=(4, 4)) for i in range(Number)]
list_product = reduce(np.dot, mylist)
```

Here `list_product` would be a 4x4 matrix holding the product of the matrices in `mylist`.